# ANY , NONE and Unit in Nim

Tags: any, nim-lang

i couldn't find any specific information in the manual. 
can anyone clarify how does ANY , NONE and type unit are reflected in Nim?

short definitions -
a unit type is a type that allows only one value (and thus can hold no information). The carrier (underlying set) associated with a unit type can be any singleton set. There is an isomorphism between any two such sets, so it is customary to talk about the unit type and ignore the details of its value. One may also regard the unit type as the type of 0-tuples, i.e. the product of no types.

ANY - 
type ANY also known as ALL or Top , is the universal set. (all possible values).

NONE- the "empty set"

thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *ANY*, *NONE* (probably `nil`) and *type unit*? Have you read the description of the tag `any`? It does not seem to have to do anything with your question. To get a proper answer, you should describe the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be about sets. Let's have a look:

```
let emptySet: set[int8] = {}
```

This is an empty set of type `int8`. The `{}` literal for the empty set is implicitly casted to any actual `set` type.

```
let singletonSet = {1'i8}
```

This is a set containing exactly one value (a *unit type* if I understand it correctly). The type of the set can now be automatically deduced from the type of the single value in it.

```
let completeSet = {low(int8) .. high(int8)}
```

This set holds all possible `int8` values.

The builtin `set` type is implemented as bitvector and thus can only be used for value types which can hold only a small set of possible values (for `int8`, the bitvector is already 256 bits long). Besides `int8`, it is usually used for `char` and enumeration types.

Then there is `HashSet` from the [module sets](http://nim-lang.org/docs/sets.html) which can hold larger types. However, if you construct a `HashSet` containing all possible values, memory consumption will probably be enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Nim is not a functional language, and never claims to be one. There is no equivalent of these types, and the solution is more like the road that c++ takes.

There is void, wich is closest to what Unit is. The Any type does not exist, but there is the untyped `pointer`. But that type does not hold any type information in it, so you need to know what you can cast it to. And for NONE, or Nothing how I know it from scala, you have to use `void`, too. But here you can add the [noReturn](http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#pragmas-noreturn-pragma) pragma.